# Gem: include my own module into ActiveModel::Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write my first gem, which has validations for credit card fields. I've created a module `MyCcValidation` and the following works:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyCcValidation
  my_validation_helper { some_data }
end
```

What I hope to achieve is to be able to add the gem to my `Gemfile` and have `my_validation_helper` available "out of the box". I tried many ways of extending `ActiveModel::Validations` but no luck so far. It's my first gem so I'm probably missing something since e.g. `devise` seems to have no problems with it. How this should be done?

Comment: you'd rather include it in ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: If so, how would that be done?

Comment: try: `ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, MyCcValidation `

Comment: tried that, `User` throws `Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant User::SomeOtherModule`. To clarify, the module extends `Concern` and has some standard validations like `validates :name, presence: true` in the `included` block.

Comment: put `ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, MyCcValidation` at the bottom of the file where you define `MyCcValidation`

Comment: that's where I put it, the error persists

Comment: please show your code and copy the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending `ActiveModel::Validations` directly does not sound like a good idea. Try to define a custom validator class with, then reopen the `ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods` module and add `your_validation_helper` there.

Example:

```
class MyCustomValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    # ...
  end
end

module ActiveModel::Validations
  module HelperMethods
    def validates_my_custom_stuff(*attr_names)
      validates_with MyCustomValidator, attr_names
    end
  end
end
```

Internally, `ActiveModel::Validations` extends HelperMethods, so your validation helper method should be available to all models.